# Weblogic transaction handling (TopLink)

Tags: transactions, ejb, weblogic, cdi, toplink

I configured two different data sources for a java application. 
These two sources are the same with one difference. One with xa and the other with non-xa transactions.

With the non-xa I  observer the behavior of database commits after each sql-statement, even if JTA does not close the transaction (does not commit). I suspect TopLink for these. e.g. a rollback after exceptions is not possible.

With the xa transaction the database commits like expected, after JPA close the connection.

xa is for global transaction (required for save transaction over multiple resources) and non-xa if we have one resources. I use only one database, so it should be possible to provide save transaction for non-xa but i'm not able to configure it or find any useful documentation about these topic.

Questions:

1. It's even possible to provide save transaction in non-xa?
2. If 1=Yes. How and why is these not default?
3. If 1=No. Why should someone use non-xa?
4. Are they any difference I need to consider for transactions in ejb or cdi about these topic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know how many details you need, but a good source of information is the [JTA Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jta-1.1-spec-oth-JSpec/)

Comment: Add this link also to your knowledge base [JDBC Data Source Transaction Options](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13737/transactions.htm#JDBCA146)

Comment: thanks for the links. I will read them as soon as possible.